# Failing to print a list in a sorted fashion without actually sorting the list

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am struggling to sort a list in a sorted fashion without actually "sorting" the list.

```
arr = [3, 2, 1, 4, 5]

count = 0
current = arr[0]
prev = -1

while count < len(arr):

    for item in arr:
        if current < item > prev:
            current = item
    prev = current
    count = count + 1
    print(current)
```

Output:

```
5
5
5
5
5
```

I don't want to sort the list. I am wondering is there a way to not sort the list and not change the original list and print the items in a sorted fashion?

Comment: _I am struggling to sort a list in a sorted fashion without actually "sorting" the list._ .... what does this mean exactly? Just sort the list.

Comment: @ggorlen that's the point. I don't want to sort the list. I am wondering is there a way to not sort the list and not change the original list and print the items in a sorted fashion?

Comment: yes, you can use sleep sort /sorry

Comment: @BrainDead was it a joke? I asked a serious question

Comment: How are you supposed to sort the list without sorting it? No, there is no way to print the items in sorted fashion without sorting it. Please explain why you don't want to/feel you can't sort the list. Maybe you mean without sorting the list in place--use `sorted(lst)` to do a non-mutating sort. If you're worried about memory constraints, you'll need to provide more details about your actual use case.

Comment: Using pointers and iteratively looking through the list and finding the next item that is still minimum but greater than the previously printed value

Comment: @Node.JS what you're suggesting is essentially writing your own sort, which is going to be slower than Python's timsort, assuming this is Python.

Comment: I completely understand, I just wanted to experiment.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with simply sorting a shallow clone of the list?  How about sorting an array containing the indices to the original list then iterating that?

Comment: While yes, "sleep sort" is a joke, it's a joke with a history.  Here's a clean JS implementation: `const sleepSort = async (xs) => Promise .all (xs .map (x => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, x, x))))`.  It will resolve to the sorted list in about `n` milliseconds, where `n` is the largest number in the list.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unclear what you're trying to do.  If you want a sorted copy, you could make a list containing the indices of the the original objects (`[0, 1, 2, ..., n]`) and then sort these by comparing the original values at those indices, then map this sorted list back to the values from the first list.

But much simpler still is just to sort a shallow clone of the list.

If you read Javascript, here's a demonstration of that idea, using a simple `range` helper function to create the list of indices:

```js
const arr = [8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]

const range = (lo, hi) => 
  [...Array (hi - lo)] .map((_, i) => lo + i)

const indexSort = (ns) =>
  range (0, ns .length)
    .sort ((i, j) => ns [i] - ns [j])
    .map (x => ns [x])

console .log ('indexSort:', indexSort (arr))

console .log ('shallow clone:', [...arr] .sort ((a, b) => a - b))

console .log ('no mutation of original array:', arr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```